# What are the benefits of JavaEE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'll be honest not sure if this is the best stack exchange question as it is board but here we go.

I'm in school for computer science and I just started a class using JavaEE. No one seems to be able to give me a straight answer. From what we have developed so far in our little labs it seems like we are creating web pages that have very nice user-interfaces?

My text book "Core JavaServer Faces" By David Geary & Cay Horstmann states in the intro you can think of it as a "Swing for server-side applications". I have seen how this can relate because our web pages have been able to store input like with php. For example if my user inputs a name and password I'm able to remember them.

Answer (score 0):

Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE) is a specification defining a collection of Java-based server and client technologies and how they inter-operate. I found an answer in the tag description for JavaEE, thanks stackoverflow. I hope this helps someone else.